# Windows Server 2012 R2 Launch Program as Local User from Code

Tags: vb.net, db2, windows-server-2012

I am trying to run an application on Server 2012 as local user (system) and hit a db2 server (on another 2012 machine), when remotely logged in.  I am trying to do this in code (VB.NET).  I'm not sure how to go about this without using 3rd party software as suggested in other posts.

I may be able to get by with getting the server user name and using that in my connection string.  But I can't seem to get that either.  The closest I can get is:

```
Dim x = Environment.UserDomainName
```

This only gives me my local user, not the server (local user) I am logged on to.  I need to launch this application (or modify my connection string, both would work) so 2012 and db2 do not throw a fit when trying to connect to the db.

**EDIT: I made this change in the execution level: http://blog.hazaveh.net/2011/05/make-your-visual-basic-application-run-as-administrator/

And it prompts to run it as admin, but works.  Any other solutions or I'll make that an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way way to force the program to launch as administrator, which solves my problem.  The answer is: [here](http://blog.hazaveh.net/2011/05/make-your-visual-basic-application-run-as-administrator/)

In the VB Project Properties, under Application Tab, the View Window Settings I changed the "RequestExecutionLevel" from "asInvoker" to "requireAdministrator".

Now, when the program is installed on the 2012 Box it is run as admin and fixes the issue I was having.